# UIRefreshControl displays above UICollectionViews Cells

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, uicollectionview

I use the following code to create the `UIRefreshControl`:

```
_refreshControl = new UIRefreshControl();
_refreshControl.ValueChanged += RefreshTriggered;
_collectionView.InsertSubview(_refreshControl, 0);
```

And I don't have any idea why the `UIRefreshControl` gets drawn over the `UICollectionViewCell`s.

Here are the subviews of the `UICollectionView` when I just added the refresh control:

```
[0]: {<UIRefreshControl: 0x7c132fe0; frame = (0 0; 594 60); hidden = YES; autoresize = W; layer = <CALayer: 0x7c133250>>}
[1]: {<UIImageView: 0x79f8a5d0; frame = (3 588.5; 588 2.5); alpha = 0; opaque = NO; autoresize = TM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x79f89a70>> - (null)}
[2]: {<UIImageView: 0x79fab7d0; frame = (588.5 584; 2.5 7); alpha = 0; opaque = NO; autoresize = LM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x796171f0>> - (null)}
```

And here are the subviews when the items are loaded in the UICollectionView:

```
[0]: {<MovieCollectionViewCell: 0x796e7350; baseClass = UICollectionViewCell; frame = (0 0; 183 278.16); clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x7c244bc0>>}
[1]: {<MovieCollectionViewCell: 0x7c2b5850; baseClass = UICollectionViewCell; frame = (186 0; 183 278.16); clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x7c2b5950>>}
[2]: {<MovieCollectionViewCell: 0x7c2ba7d0; baseClass = UICollectionViewCell; frame = (0 281; 183 278.16); clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x7c2ba8d0>>}
[3]: {<MovieCollectionViewCell: 0x7c2bf440; baseClass = UICollectionViewCell; frame = (186 281; 183 278.16); clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x7c2bf540>>}
[4]: {<MovieCollectionViewCell: 0x7c2c42d0; baseClass = UICollectionViewCell; frame = (0 562.5; 183 278.16); clipsToBounds = YES; hidden = YES; opaque = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x7c2c43d0>>}
[5]: {<MovieCollectionViewCell: 0x7c2c9160; baseClass = UICollectionViewCell; frame = (186 562.5; 183 278.16); clipsToBounds = YES; hidden = YES; opaque = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x7c2c9260>>}
[6]: {<UIRefreshControl: 0x7c132fe0; frame = (0 -69.5; 369 60); autoresize = W; layer = <CALayer: 0x7c133250>>}
[7]: {<UIImageView: 0x7c159e80; frame = (3 522; 363 2.5); alpha = 0; opaque = NO; autoresize = TM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x7c159fb0>> - (null)}
[8]: {<UIImageView: 0x7c15a480; frame = (363.5 -66.5; 2.5 224); opaque = NO; autoresize = LM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x7c15a5b0>> - (null)}
```

Anyone an idea?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try sending the `refreshControll` to the back after the layout process like this :

```
- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews
{
    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];

    [self.collectionView sendSubviewToBack:self.refreshControl];
}
```

Because `UITableView` and `UICollectionView` reuse their cells, they have a very specific way of laying out their subviews (probably through a custom implementation of `layoutSubviews`). As a result, the position at which you insert a custom subview is usually not kept after the layout process. This is why you have to override `viewDidLayoutSubviews` and put your view back where you want it.

`UIRefreshControll` is automatically detected by `UITableView` and put back behind other subviews, but it's not the case for `UICollectionView` and you have to do it manually. And for any other custom subview, you would have to do it for both `UITableView` and `UICollectionView`.

Comment: Well this works, and I'm going to mark it as resolved, but I'd like to see an explanation as to why this happens. I think this is a bug either in Xamarin or iOS.

Comment: See my edit. Things have been working this way for as long as I can remember so I wouldn't call it a bug, just something you need too know...